# When navigating to a different web page from a webpage should the URL of the new webpage contain the endpoint of the previous web page?

Tags: html, url, redirect

Suppose I have a web page let's say rooms.html and the URL of that page is "http://localhost:8000/hotel/rooms/". In that HTML page there is a link to add_room.html page, when I click on that link, I get redirected to add_room.html whose URL is "http://localhost:8000/hotel/add_room/". I want to know what should I keep the UPL of this page. Should it be "http://localhost:8000/hotel/add_room/" or "http://localhost:8000/hotel/rooms/add_room/". So bascically my question is that when navigating to a different web page from a webpage should the URL of the new webpage contain the endpoint of the previous web page?